# Control 5 V buzzer using 5 V microcontroller (which can't drive it directly) and a single 5 V power supply?

Tags: avr, speakers

I have a [PB-12N23PW-05Q](https://www.mgelectronic.rs/ProductFilesDownload?Id=4123) buzzer and I'm trying to use it with ATmega 162. I can't connect it directly to pin, because from what I've read from 162's datasheet, it can source at most 20 mA. The buzzer takes 50 (or around 25, if we take a look at the graph), so I don't think I can just directly connect it to the microcontroller.

My initial idea was to connect it to a transistor and use the transistor as a switch.  Unfortunately, it didn't work. I used BD237 and my idea was that the microcontroler will pull the pin connected to the base high and the transistor will operate the buzzer. In my setup, I had buzzer connected to Vcc, buzzer's negative port connected to collector, GND connected to the emitter and 162 connected to the base. Transistor is of NPN type. Somewhere I read that this way some problems related to the voltage drop on the transistor can be mitigated, but to me it looks like the voltage drop is the main problem here.

Here's the schematic. The mc is used instead of switch on the real thing.

[image: buzzer circuit schematic]

Right now, I'm looking for other ideas on how to connect the buzzer.

Comment: Does it work if you connect it directly to 5V?

Comment: @reemrevnivek Yes.

Comment: Double check the pin out of the transistor.  Post a schematic if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Robert  I've added a schematic.

Comment: Try using a different transistor and limit the base current with a resistor per the datasheet.

Comment: Can you measure the voltage between the emitter and collector while you have the transistor on? Are you sure you don't have the emitter and collector swapped on your board? Are you sure you haven't killed your transistor (Vbe max = 5V)? This should work and the transistor has plenty of power to drive a 50mA load.

Comment: use a mosfet then you wont need a series R

Comment: Doesn't the microcontroller have a resistor inside on the pin?

Comment: As for the resistor, would 250 ohm be good enough?

Comment: @AndrejaKo The micro does not have a resistor inside the pin. It only has a maximum specified output current which, when exceeded, may release magic smoke. Use Ohm's law to specify the resistor.

Comment: @joeforker OK. Thanks! I definitely don't want to let the magic smoke go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for posting and linking to exactly which sound-maker you are trying to use: the [PB-12N23PW-05Q](http://www.hitpoint.com.tw/main.php?product=acoustic&db=ac_pb&type=dc&id=10) self-oscillating buzzer.
(If you had a raw piezo disk, or a coil speaker, we would use a different drive circuit).

If you insist on using a NPN such as the BD237, you need to add a external resistor between the MCU and the base of the NPN, as joeforker mentioned: 1 KOhm should be adequate.
But no matter what resistor or silicon NPN transistor you use, you will end up with (at best) a V_ce_sat voltage drop of around 0.6 V, so the voltage across the buzzer is about 4.4 V -- which is technically outside the "guaranteed-to-work" "4.5 to 5.5 V" operating range in the buzzer datasheet.

If I were you, I would probably throw out the NPN and replace it with a MOSFET.
A cheap 2N7000 has an on-resistance of 5 Ohm; at 25 mA that gives a voltage drop of .125 V.
(More expensive MOSFETs have an order of magnitude less (better) on-resistance).

The MOSFET should work in the circuit you posted -- it doesn't need a resistor.

I am surprised that you are getting a different sound.
The kinds of mistakes I am likely to make (and so the first things I would check) are:

- Did I put the buzzer in upside down?
  (This doesn't matter much for a raw piezo disk, but it does matter in a self-oscillating buzzer like yours).
- Hook the buzzer up to a bench power supply, and see what it sounds like in the 4 V to 5 V voltage range. Perhaps it's supposed to sound like that at that (5V - transistor drop) voltage?
- What is the actual voltage across the buzzer and across the transistor?
  I might check this with an O'scope, since it's quite possible that we have an *average* current of 25 mA, as shown on the graph, but peak pulses of much higher current -- perhaps such a high instantaneous current that your so-called "5 V" power supply is briefly pulled down to such a low voltage that your ATmega resets.
  If that is the case, you'll need to add some bypass capacitors and perhaps a ferrite bead or resistor.

Comment: I'd guess that the different sound is due to the decreased voltage which would change the oscillation frequency.

Comment: @davidcary  I just tested the buzzer on voltages form 2.7 V to 5.5 V and it doesn't make the sound I can hear from the microcontroller on any of those voltages. The sound does change with voltage, but it's very different to what I'm getting. On direct power supply, it sounds like speaker on a new computer case or a fax modem, while on controller, it sounds like a whine of a SMPS mixed with ticking sound. I'll try measuring voltage on the buzzer when I'm running it form the microcontroller and report back.

Comment: @davidcary Alo, I never used FETs before, so could I use IRF9540N (P-type, 100V, 23A, 140W, Rds:0.117Ω) or IRFZ44N (N-type, 55V, 49A, 94W, Rds:0.0175Ω) instead? They have the advantage of being easily obtainable here.

Comment: I'm getting 4.97 V on the buzzer terminals. For the transistor, I get Emitter-Collector -0.064 V, Collector-Base -0.502 V (sound changes when measuring), Emitter-Base -0.0569. I don't have a real scope available, but the current theory is probably correct. At first, I connected the buzzer to the decoupling capacitors and ATmega kept resetting. Now I connected it directly to the power pins on the board and I don't have power problems with ATmega.

Comment: I used IRFZ44N and buzzer sounds normal now.

Comment: I'm happy it's working for you now -- yay! Yes, N-type should work with the schematic you posted +5V -- buzzer -- NFET -- GND. P-type should work if you shuffle the order so you have +5V -- PFET -- buzzer -- GND. Using what is easily available is smart -- but if you go into production, FETs that have 1/10 the cost will probably work just as well.

Comment: 0.6 V for the saturation voltage of a small signal transistor is too high.  Plan on around 0,1 V or less.  The 0.064 V measurement is a reasonable value.